# How do I know when the PR2 switches from wireless to wired networking

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I plug in a network cable into the back of the PR2, who do I know it is actually using the wired network and not the wireless network?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9327/how-do-i-know-when-the-pr2-switches-from-wireless-to-wired-networking/) by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2915 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Network-switching is controlled by the utility "multi_interface_roam."  This utility produces useful information in the log file: "/var/log/roam/console-output.log"

To monitor it, run:

`tail -f /var/log/roam/console-output.log`

You will see a description of the 3 possible networking interfaces.  lan1 (the service port), wan0, or the ddwrt.  The active interface will show up in the far right column.

For example, if you are on wireless, you will see:

```
2011-03-07 16:38:33,918 - INFO -    bs@lan1   inf  Wired    0.000 100
2011-03-07 16:38:33,918 - INFO -       wan0  15.0  NoLink  -2.000  -2
2011-03-07 16:38:33,919 - INFO -      ddwrt   inf  Wired   56.976 100 active
```

*Note: "ddwrt" shows up as a wired interface because it is wired from the computer to the ddwrt router*

If you are on wired, you should see:

```
2011-03-07 17:01:35,952 - INFO -    bs@lan1   inf  Wired   0.000 100
2011-03-07 17:01:35,952 - INFO -       wan0   inf  Wired 100.000 100 active
2011-03-07 17:01:35,953 - INFO -      ddwrt   inf  Wired  99.990 100 #2
```

---

Originally posted by [leibs](https://answers.ros.org/users/6/leibs/) with karma: 126 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-07**:
Perhaps this is something to add on the PR2 dashboard, as the connection influences the performance of the PR2.